# Error en Python 3.8 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x

No sé qué más le falta a esto, no entiendo porque me da el error o como resolverlo.
Estoy siguiendo un vídeo de youtube, el tío lo hace y a él le funciona, estoy seguro que hago lo mismo que él ha hecho. ¿Alguna ayuda? os dejo el link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chy-32X2tqk&t=588s Hora 3, minuto 53  de vídeo. Gracias.

```
def divide(dividend, divisor):
    if divisor != 0:
        print(dividend / divisor)
    else:
       print("You Fool!")

divide(15, divisor=0)
```

Comment: Tu `else` tiene **1 espacio de menos** con respecto al `if`. ¿ Error de copy/paste o lo tienes así en tu código ?

Comment: El `else` debe estar identado al mismo nivel que el `if`. Pon un espacio más antes de `else` y **otro delante de `print("You Fool!")`** (debe estar al mismo nivel que el `print` anterior). En Python la identación determina los bloques de código. Fijate en el vídeo y verá a lo que me refiero...

Comment: error de copy/paste.Ya lo edité. Gracias. Pero el error sigue :/

Comment: Hola Emerson DSS, como comentaba arriba, al `print` del `else` le falta también un espacio...

Comment: Hey :) acabo de probar darle un espacio más al print(), lo que cambó es que ya no me aparece el error pero no retorna nada tampoco... Mira que es una tontería pero me tiene rayado.

Comment: Eso no es posible, bueno, la función no retorna nada, pero un print te tiene que aparecer al llamarla... Te dejo un enlace al código en repl.it para que lo puedas probar online: https://repl.it/repls/SeveralLovelyRepositories

Comment: Gracias Maquina =)

Comment: Serán fallos tontos de principiante, no me lo explico, lo copié y pegué en repl.it, lo ejecuté, funcionó...Voy al VSC,lo pego, ctrl-s, ejecuto, y funciona... Gracias por vuestra ayuda, ya me puedo ir a dormir en paz ':D